# DataVirtualization with RadDataPager and RadGridView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, telerik, radgridview

I am using `RadDataPager` and `RadGridView` in conjunction to display and page data. It works fine till database(SQL) rows are in thousands. But as they reach millions application is extremely slow. So my question is how to correctly use `RadDataPager` and `RadGridView` together.

Just to take a simple example using code-beind:

**CodeBehind:**

```
public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();

     var db = new LinqToSqlDataContext();  
     var query = db.Logs; //Millions of rows here.
     var view = new VirtualQueryableCollectionView(query) { LoadSize = 50 };

     DataContext = view;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
 <telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollMode="Deferred"/>
 <telerik:RadDataPager Source="{Binding}"/>
```

Comment: have you checked the `Telerik` support web page for examples would be my first question.

Comment: Ofcourse I did check [this page](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/populating-with-data/Populating-DataVirtualization), and a nice [blog here](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/q1-2010-new-feature-paging-with-radgridview-for-silverlight-and-wpf) which gives many examples. All of them load all the data initially from database and then page them. It is kind of UI Virtualization, but they dont work if I bind them to my DB.

Comment: what about here http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-binding/simple-vs-advanced/defaultcs.aspx || http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/consuming-data/using-data-virtualization

Comment: Your second link is what exactly what I am doing. But I need to implement the suggestions given in your first link. I will try implementing them and come back with results.

Comment: you should be able to implement what is going on in the first link.. let me know

Comment: I looked into it, but the event ` NeedDataSource` isn't available for WPF applications. And no other matching events are found.